# Xcode 8.1 trouble adding storyboard for iPad to universal app with existing iPhone storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

My app has been universal and has had iPhone storyboard.
It works great.

Now I want to run it on iPad.  Xcode complained of missing iPad storyboard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can just click into the Main_iPad.storyboard and do a CMD+V to paste what you have copied to the clipboard from your original storyboard

Comment: Thanks.  I had to click around until Paste got enabled.  Pasted ok.  But got another error (see above).

Comment: You need to click on your first view controller and there is a checkbox on it that says "initial view controller"... that error should go away once that checkbox is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I did File > New > User Interface > Storyboard and
2. named it "Main_iPad.storyboard". (Existing one has been Main.storyboard)
3. Went in to Main.storyboard > Select All > Copy
4. Went in to Main_iPad.storyboard and pasted.
5. Main_iPadStoryboard > select ViewControll > its properties > set "Is Initial View Controller"
6. Ran it and it works